# get my script right Google Sheets onEdit script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

So I tried to write this code in the script editor,
but it seems that is not working.

```
function onEdit() {
var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Sheet1");
var range = sheet.getRange("A2:D");
range.sort(\[{column: 1, ascending: true}, {column: 4, ascending: true}\]);
}
```

I'm trying to auto-sort by two columns in the range A2:D every time a new line adds to the sheets. Can someone help, please?

I'm trying to auto-sort by two columns in the range A2:D every time a new line adds to the sheets. Can someone help, please?

Answer (score 1):

This works for me:

```
function onEdit(e) {
  //e.source.toast("Entry");//just for debugging
  var sheet = e.range.getSheet();
  var range = sheet.getRange("A2:D"+sheet.getLastRow());
  range.sort([{ column: 1, ascending: true }]);
}
```

Comment: What is the purpose of ` e.source.toast("Entry");`? Just a visual indicator?

Comment: I just use it to tell me the trigger has fired